# Calling a web service on PubNub Presence events

Tags: pubnub

When using the PubNub Presence feature, is it possible to provide a HTTP callback that PubNub calls when a user joins or leaves a channel? In my case I want to call a Parse.com cloud function.
To clarify: I don't want to call the function from a client, but have the PubNub.com servers take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calling a web service on PubNub Presence events

PubNub offers Presence "HTTP Callback" generated from PubNub.com servers. You must ask your Account Manager to enable for you; send an email to support@pubnub.com to enable.  Ask for **`"Presence Callback Active"`** and **`"Presence Callback Inactive"`** settings.  You'll want to setup a dev/prod key pair to point the WebHook URLs at different environments.

> The [HTTP callback URL that is triggered when a channel becomes active](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/84/webhooks-and-url-callbacks-with-pubnub-presence).

Webhooks are now supported for all presence events: join, leave, timeout and state-change, as well as the channel active and inactive events.

For a full explanation please read [this StackOverflow about PubNub Presence Webhooks and how to get them configured for you keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853515/pubnub-presence-detection-of-all-the-channels-together-without-subscribing-to-an/33858488#33858488).